# Paginate relationship in Laravel with first

Tags: php, laravel

I ran into a question, what would be a best way to paginate relationships in Laravel?

For instance:

```
$category = $this->blogCategory->whereId($categoryId)->with(['blogPosts'])->first();
```

Here I'm getting all required data, but what about pagination for relationships? I have stripped categories by `first()` to retrieve the first category, but how to paginate relationship `blogPosts` that is `morphToMany` type of multiple blog posts? what would be a better way to achieve that?

EDIT:

So I come up with this at this moment.

```
        $category = $this->blogCategory->whereId($categoryId)->with(['blogPosts' => function ($query) {

            $query->paginate(1);
         
         }])->first();
```

Though it doesn't prints out `current_page`, but works like `limit`.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, it should work, As it work for me in laravel 5.4

```
$category = $this->blogCategory->whereId($categoryId)->first()->with(['blogPosts'])->paginate(1);
```

Comment: doesn't work in laravel 8 in the right way, it paginates categories, not relations(and they seem to be ignored).

Comment: from [https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#dynamic-relationships] 
`$this->blogCategory->whereId($categoryId)->first()->blogPosts()->paginate(1);`
definitely it will work

Comment: Thanks, the relationship is work indeed, but now ```blogCategory``` nothing prints out - only relationship

Comment: Use either


`$category = $this->blogCategory->whereId($categoryId)->first();
$category->setRelation('blogPosts', $category->blogPosts()->paginate(10));
`

OR


`$category = $this->blogCategory->whereId($categoryId)->first();
$blogPosts = $category->blogPosts()->paginate(10);
return view('page', compact('category', 'blogPosts'));`

Comment: Well, I was looking for the way to get all in one line, but thanks for your efforts. Seems there's no other way so, eh. Edit your answer with this comment, I'll flag it as proper response.